# Move file to folders while creating folders

Tags: python, directory

I have some files and I want to move them to some folders. I made the code which create these folders based on number of files. How can I move the files to each folder (better if directly when creating each one) ?

```
import os
import errno

src = (os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\output8\\singola\\'))

causali = os.listdir(src)
causali.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]))

for file in enumerate(causali):
    try:
        id_folder = os.makedirs(os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\output8\\singola\\{}'.format(file[0])))
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise
```

Something like this..

[image: example]

Comment: All of your files is under one directory? and you want to move them to different directories?

Comment: look at python library `shutil`

Comment: @mtkilic I am using shutil but I can't understand the string format logic to do this. I found another way to do the job but I don't like it.

Comment: can you please explain what you trying to do more clearly. So you have some files in directory and you want to move each file to its own folder?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Best if this action performs right after the creation of the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.rename()` or `shutil.move()`, they both have the same syntax.

```
os.rename("path/to/current/file.foo", "path/to/new/desination/for/file.foo")
shutil.move("path/to/current/file.foo", "path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo")
```

In your case,

```
import os
import errno

src = (os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\output8\\singola\\'))

causali = os.listdir(src)
causali.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]))

for file in enumerate(causali):
   try:
        id_folder = os.makedirs(os.path.expanduser('~/test_move/{}'.format(file[0])))
        os.rename(os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\output8\\singola\\{}'.format(file[1])),os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\output8\\singola\\{}\\{}'.format(file[0],file[1])))
   except OSError as e:path/to/new/destination/for/file
        if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise
```

Comment: Great, I am now sure that it is going to stick to your mind more. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

Below code will create sub directory(folder) for each filename in your directory, name of the folders will be same as your filename. And each file will be move to the folder has same name.

```
import glob, os, shutil                                                                     
source = "C:\\Users\\xx\\Desktop\\Folder"

for file_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(source, '*.*')):
    new_sub_folder = file_path.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(source, new_sub_folder))
    shutil.move(file_path, os.path.join(new_sub_folder, os.path.basename(file_path)))
```